# List has no rows for assignment and Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.name'

Tags: apex, visualforce

> List has no rows for assignment and Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.name'

Everything works fine when I have values but if I have no values then this error occur while searching I came to know that I have to change object to list.If I change then this error occur

> Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.name'

I give some part of my code

---

Visual force component:

```
<apex:component controller="LongProjectOrderController" access="global" rendered="true">
  <apex:attribute description="lpo" name="lpo"  type="SalesOrder__c"/>
<table align="right">
<tr>
<td><b>Order No:</b></td>
<td>{!lpo.Name}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Raised By:</b></td>
<td>{!lpo.CreatedBy.Name}</td>
</tr>
</table>

  <table>
 <tr>
<td><b>Summary of agreed Payment Schedule:</b></td>
<td><apex:outputText rendered="{!(ChildRecords.Room1_Payment_Include_In_Print__c == true)}" value="{!ChildRecords.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_Room1__c}" /></td>
<td><apex:outputText rendered="{!(ChildRecords.Room2_Payment_Include_In_Print__c == true)}" value="{!ChildRecords.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_Room2__c}" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</apex:component>
```

Conroller:

```
public with sharing class LongProjectOrderController {
public String MasterRecordId        {get; set;}

    public Project__c ChildRecords{get; set;}

    public LongProjectOrderController()
    {
     MasterRecordId =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

      if(!String.isBlank(MasterRecordId)){


                 ChildRecords =
                [
                    SELECT Name,CreatedBy.Name,Room1_Payment_Include_In_Print__c,Room2_Payment_Include_In_Print__c

                    FROM
                        Project__c
                    WHERE 
                        Long_Project_Order__c = :MasterRecordId
                ];
                system.debug('###########################');

    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the posted answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has answers all over the place and a quick search with yield answers. But alas......

When performing SOQL and assigning to an sObject Queries dereference into an instance of that sObject as long as there is exactly 1 record returned. A convenience that when not understood or used properly will cause unnecessary issues.

inorder to cover all bases you should be assigning the results of the SOQL to a

```
List<sObject>
```

So:

```
public Project__c[] childRecords {get; set;}

ChildRecords =
            [
                SELECT Name,CreatedBy.Name,Room1_Payment_Include_In_Print__c,Room2_Payment_Include_In_Print__c

                FROM
                    Project__c
                WHERE 
                    Long_Project_Order__c = :MasterRecordId
            ];
```

Will not throw an error when no records or more than 1 record is returned. then you can check the size of the results like so and do the needful

```
childRecords.isEmpty()
```

Now, the `Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.name'` will only occur if you are trying to use `{!childRecords.name}` on the Vf page as it is a list so you would need to iterate using a repeat. I do not see anything in the page code you posted that would throw that error.

However, you could do this (assuming you implemented the above):

```
public Project__c childRecord {

   get{
       if(childRecords.isEmpty())
           return new Project__c();
       else
           return childRecords[0];
   }
}
```

Then:

```
<td>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!(ChildRecord.Room1_Payment_Include_In_Print__c == true)}" value="{!ChildRecords.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_Room1__c}" />
</td>
<td>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!(ChildRecord.Room2_Payment_Include_In_Print__c == true)}" value="{!ChildRecords.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_Room2__c}" />
</td>
```

Adjust to meet needs as the above is to illustrate principles and not best practice

Comment: Well as a beginner I have some trouble of making that. I don't know whom to ask that's why I am put here.Now I understand how simple that is and what it is thanks for instant response.

Comment: @SankarGanesh - Do you still have questions? Being a beginner I am going to point out that when your questions are answered it is common to make them as accepted so the question with answers can be found when others search for a similar problem